# Уведомление постоянно свернутое Android

Tags: java, android

Как сделать уведомление развернутым по умолчанию?

```
String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.simpleapp";
        String channelName = "My Background Service";
        NotificationChannel chan = null;
            chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            assert manager != null;
            manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);
            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ua_radio_logo)
                    .setCustomBigContentView(contentView)
                    .build();
                
                    startForeground(1, notification);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Судя по [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51514404/3212712) сделать такое нельзя. Но можно заставить систему (не на всех девайсах) развернуть уведомление с наивысшим приоритетом (оно должно быть самым верхним в шторке):

```
.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
```

Comment: Пробовал не работает

Comment: YouTube music и Zaycev fm как-то удалось это сделать

Comment: @AndrewSAV, а если `Notification.PRIORITY_MAX` использовать?

Comment: @AndrewSAV, ещё можно попробовать раздел 4 из этой статьи: https://medium.com/@shashankmohabia/android-notifications-3-expandable-notifications-and-notifications-groups-1cfed308fe3a Но, возможно, придётся переделывать уведомление, убирая/модифицируя кастомную разметку.

Comment: Notification.PRIORITY_MAX пробовал не подходит.
Статью уже читал, тоже пробовал.

Comment: интересно то, что когда присутствует только мое уведомление, оно открывается сразу полностью, а когда есть еще какое-уведомление, тогда мое сворачивается

Comment: Может ещё с NotificationChannel и его последним аргументом поиграться?